# React change state for all elements except for the chosen one

Tags: reactjs, events, state

I have a bunch of buttons that change style on events such as hover, click etc.

I want to do a simple operation with onClick event to highlight the pressed button.

It's doing well but then other buttons need to get rid of the class that highlights them (`'light-active'` and '`sect-active'`). These classes don't go away because the state `isActive` is true as the button was pressed before.

I can't come up with a solution.
Here's my code: **(please note that I refer to buttons as 'pages')**

*App.js* - Root

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PageButtons from './components/PageButtons';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import PageBody from './components/PageBody';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    pages: [
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: 'Body',
        active: false,
      },
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: 'Parents',
        active: false,
      },
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: 'Head',
        active: false,
      },
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: 'Face',
        active: false,
      },
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: 'Hair',
        active: false,
      },
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: 'Accessories',
        active: false,
      },
    ],
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div id='container' style={cont}>
          <PageButtons pages={this.state.pages} />
          <PageBody />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const cont = {
  padding: '1em',
  width: '40vw',
  display: 'grid',
  placeContent: 'center',
};

export default App;
```

*PageButton**s**.js* - Parent component for buttons

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PageButton from './PageButton';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class PageButtons extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={pagesStyle}>
        {this.props.pages.map((page) => (
          <PageButton
            key={page.id}
            page={page}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const pagesStyle = {
  alignSelf: 'end',
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'nowrap',
  overflowX: 'auto',
  overflowY: 'hidden',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  width: '30vw',
  marginBottom: '1vw',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  padding: '1.3vw',
};

// PropTypes
PageButtons.propTypes = {
  pages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default PageButtons;
```

*PageButton.js* - the buttons

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class PageButton extends Component {
  state = {
    isHovered: false,
    isActive: false,
  };

  handleHover = () => {
    this.setState({ isHovered: !this.state.isHovered });
  };

  handleMouseDown = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: !this.state.isActive });
  };
  

  render() {
    const isHovered = this.state.isHovered;
    const isActive = this.state.isActive;
    const { id, title } = this.props.page;
    return (
      <div
        id='singlePageBtnStyle'
        className='page'
        onMouseEnter={this.handleHover}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleHover}
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
      >
        <div
          className={`light ${
            isHovered ? 'light-2' : [isActive ? 'light-active' : 'light']
          }`}
        ></div>
        <div
          className={`sect ${
            isHovered ? 'sect-2' : [isActive ? 'sect-active' : 'sect']
          }`}
        >
          <p
            dataText={title}
            style={{ margin: 'auto' }}
            className={`${isHovered ? 'glitch' : ''}`}
          >
            {title}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PageButton;
```

Comment: What/where is your `handleMouseUp` handler attached and used to clear the active state? Manually managing hover state in JS will also have issues, better to use CSS for the `:hover` styles.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the reply, no need to worry about this handler, it's there in case I need to use it. I just want to know how to switch classes on and off of multiple elements =)

Comment: Are you referring to the two `div` elements? Those are toggled by the mouse up/down handlers, according to your snippet. How are you trying to unset the active state?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, we are talking about the two divs. How am I unsetting the state? That's exactly what I want to find out =)

Comment: It seems you allude to other buttons (potentially also active). What is the expected behavior, can you describe more what you want the interaction to be? Usually in situations where you want to "de-toggle" buttons the active state would be "lifted" to a parent component that maintains the entire active state of all the buttons. You've encapsulated the active state to each button, so they more or less act independently.

Comment: @DrewReese  I think I should also say that there is an array in the parent component which has a state and within it an array. Each item in the array has properties for each button. It has a title, an id and a property called 'active: false/true' . The last property isn't used but I feel like it could be the answer to my question. (i'll continue in the next comment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227069/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-liana-meyer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only a single button to be active at-a-time, IMO it make more sense to use a separate slice of state to hold an active id/index/etc... (*The alternative would be to shallow copy the entire `pages` array just to toggle false all the `active` properties and the 1 single true active property*)

Remove the `active` property from your `App` state. The state here should just drive the content for the menu items.

```
state = {
  pages: [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title: 'Body',
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title: 'Parents',
    },
    ...
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title: 'Accessories',
    },
  ],
};
```

Let `PageButtons` hold the active page/button state. Create a toggle handler and pass as an `onClick` handler to `PageButton` along with a computed `isActive` prop.

```
class PageButtons extends Component {
  state = {
    activeId: null,
  }

  // NOTE: Curried function to consume id and return onClick handler function
  toggleActive = id => e => this.setState(({ activeId }) => ({
    activeId: activeId === id ? null : id, // toggle same id off, or set new
  }));

  render() {
    const { activeId } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={pagesStyle}>
        {this.props.pages.map((page) => (
          <PageButton
            isActive={activeId === page.id} // <-- compute if active
            onMouseOver={this.handleClick}
            onClick={this.toggleActive(page.id)} // <-- enclose id in callback
            key={page.id}
            page={page}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Page button should consume these new props. Add the `onClick` handler where it makes sense and set the active classname by the `isActive` prop.

```
class PageButton extends Component {
  state = {
    isHovered: false,
  };

  handleHover = () => {
    this.setState(({ isHovered }) => ({ isHovered: !isHovered }));
  };

  render() {
    const { isHovered } = this.state;
    const { isActive, onClick, page: { id, title } } = this.props;

    return (
      <div
        id='singlePageBtnStyle'
        className='page'
        onMouseEnter={this.handleHover}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleHover}
        onClick={onClick} // <-- attach onClick handler
      >
        <div
          className={`light ${
            isHovered ? 'light-2' : [isActive ? 'light-active' : 'light']
          }`}
        ></div>
        <div
          className={`sect ${
            isHovered ? 'sect-2' : [isActive ? 'sect-active' : 'sect']
          }`}
        >
          <p
            dataText={title}
            style={{ margin: 'auto' }}
            className={`${isHovered ? 'glitch' : ''}`}
          >
            {title}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```